# ¿Variable estatica que no se deja asignar?

Tags: c#, wpf

Buen día, Tengo un código hecho por mi en el cual manejo una variable estática para controlar ciertas acciones en otros formularios, el detalle es que la primera vez que la utilizo ésta se comporta como lo espero, pero de ahí en adelante se queda con el valor 0 y (a pesar de que explicitamente la coloco en 1, 2 o 3). cabe destacar que la variable es de tipo entero.

este es el código que le da un valor dependiendo del botón que se presione en el programa

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    opcion = 1;
    Close();
}
```

Como se pueden imaginar aquí la estoy trabajando en el mismo formulario en el que esta declarada.

la variable esta definida así:

```
public static int opcion = 0;
```

cuando depuro y paso por la instrucción `opcion = 1;` y pongo el ratón sobre la variable esta sigue mostrando 0.

¿estoy haciendo algo mal? intente ponerle el modificador `volatile` para ver si el problema era el no poder acceder a la variable, pero no funciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias definir esa variable en una clase separada, o sea

```
public static class Global
{
   public static int opcion = 0;
}
```

entonces desde el boton harias

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Global.opcion = 1;
    Close();
}
```

desde los otras windows usarías `Global.opcion` para acceder al dato

De esta forma no dejas la variable definida en una ventana cuando la idea es accederla de forma global.

Comment: las mejores soluciones son las mas sencillas, buena idea, no lo habia pensado asi, aunque igual me parece un poco raro el que no me deje cambiar mas de una vez el valor de la variable estando en el ambito en el que fue declarada...

gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Me pregunto porque el -1 si la solución más simple es indicada por acceder a la variable definida como global :|

Comment: hola @Elenasys, sabes que me preguntaba lo mismo, seria bueno si votan negativo al menos den alguna justificacion, asi uno puede mejorar la respuesta y aprender que le falto

Comment: la intención de la justificación de -1 se supone no es necesaría pero como mencionas ayuda a mejorar nuestras respuestas, lo cual es importante.